# LTspice model single-phase motorcycle alternator

Tags: motor, ltspice, simulation, alternator

These days I'm dabbling in the design of a regulator for a 50cc motorbike, and I have a doubt how I can simulate the alternator on LTspice. Doing various tests on LTspice I arrived at a sinusoidal generator connected in series to an inductance (the value of the inductance and randomly that I still have to measure it).

[image]

What is the correct way to simulate it?

Comment: Have you tried googling "modelling an alternator in ltspice"?

Comment: [This web search](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/how-to-simulate-a-car-alternator-in-ltspice.166158/) looks like it offers some promising links.

Comment: That was one result of quite a few using search string: modelling an alternator in ltspice

Comment: Note that a ground symbol is always needed in LTspice.  And "floating legs" i.e. V1 negative and L1 unconnected wire generally result in a convergence failure (inability to simulate.)  Add a ground symbol, and tie L1 to ground through a high-value resistor, and it should simulate.

Comment: Instead of a voltage source use a CCVS (the `h` element), with the expression `L1 <value>`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  Is using an inductor instead of a voltage source within an H-source definition documented anywhere?

Comment: @SteKulov Oof, you got me. I don't think it is but, don't quote me. I think it's just that "it is known" how the inductor is represented in SPICE, internally, so it just went on from there (confirmed by practice). To my surprise I found out that also not many people knew about the possible usage of the VCVS as the current sensor. It's a wonderful world.

Comment: @rdtsc the image and for illustration purposes only on the simulation i am doing the ground reference is inserted

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen could you be a little more specific, on how to set the CCVS

Comment: @ErikMedeossi Just as I said: use its value as you see it, e.g. `L1 1` will make it generate a voltage 1:1 proportional to the current, `L1 0.5` will mean a voltage worth half the current. Be careful with the sign: you can `RClick` on the inductor and check the "show phase dot" (the direction of the current will be towards the dot).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thanks a lot for the clarification